If Psalm 110 was NOT written by David, then did Jesus make an error in stating that "David himself calls him [the messiah] 'lord'" in the Psalm?
If Psalm 110 was NOT written by David, then did Jesus make an error in stating that "David himself calls him [the messiah] 'lord'" in the Psalm (Mark 12:36-37; Mat. 22:43-45; Luke 20:42-44), or is there a better way of looking at this?
I've read a few commentaries (expositional and scholarly) on the New Testament passages and Psalm in question (Expositor's Bible Commentary: Carson (Matthew), Wessel and Strauss (Mark), Liefeld and Pao (Luke), VanGemeren (Psalms); Word Biblical Commentary: Evans (Mark), Hagner (Matthew), Nolland (Luke), Allen (Psalms 101-150); and the NET Bible's notes to name a few). At least one of the Expositor's commentators recommended Allen's commentary. I agree that his appears to provide the most thorough analysis of the Psalm's original context of the commentaries I've read and also best addresses the question at hand. While he concludes that the Psalm was most likely written about David rather than by David (as also the NET concludes), he also writes,

"An understanding of the heading of the psalm in terms of Davidic authorship features twice in argumentation, at Mark 12:35–37 (and parallels) and Acts 2:33. This understanding, already as old in principle as the redactional characterization of the block of Davidic psalms in Pss 3–71 as “the prayers of David son of Jesse” in Ps 72:20, accords with what R. N. Longenecker has called the “circumstantial” or “descriptive” type of interpretation, based on ancient cultural norms, to be found in the NT, as distinct from the normative kind of exegesis practiced today (TynBul 21 [1970] 36–38; Biblical Exegesis, 193–98)."

I've since read some of the recommended book by Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis in the Apostolic Period, learning much about Jewish exegetical practices around the 1st century. I also read Dr. Michael Brown's take on Jesus' use of Psalm 110 in his book, Answering Jewish Objections to Jesus, Vol. 3. While he prefers defending the Psalm originally being written about the Messiah, he also concedes,

"Even if the psalm was originally written by a court poet for his lord, King David, it would still point to David’s priestly calling (as a prototype of the Messiah) as well as to his worldwide reign, fulfilled only through David’s greater descendant, King Messiah. This would mean, then, that Jesus was pointing to Jewish interpretation of the day, interpretation that attributed the authorship of this psalm to David, thereby proving that Messiah had to be greater than David, but without making a definitive statement about the authorship of the psalm."

This is the best and most direct answer I've found so far. The difficulty now is reconciling the assumption that Jesus was not "making a definitive statement about the authorship of the psalm" with the language that he uses, which appears to be definitive. Matthew's version seems to be most easily reconciled with this approach, since Davidic authorship is merely an assumed part of Jesus' questions to his opponents. Mark and Luke are more difficult, Mark's version reading, "David himself said by the Holy Spirit,... David himself calls him 'Lord'." (I also explored the possibility that David could merely be a colloquial designation for the Davidic Psalms, attempting to replace David with the Davidic author in Jesus' quote. This, however, doesn't seem to work well, since the argument in the gospels revolves around the question of how the messiah could be David's son, whenever David, the assumed author of the Psalm, calls him 'Lord'.)
I also have some deeper questions, which I think are pertinent to how we answer the main question:

Does Jesus himself believe that David wrote the psalm? (It's easier to account for other New Testament writers' use of Jewish tradition, since they aren't themselves divine.) If so, how should that inform our Christology? (Which part of His argument is divine and which part is human?)
Is the point Jesus tries to make undermined if his argument is based on a false premise?
If Jesus said that David wrote this Psalm, but it actually wasn't written by David, how do we reconcile that with the doctrine of inerrancy?


Welcome Lucas, even if the author was not David... it was written for him and David honored it by saving it. I am certain there were more then 151 Psalms written :)

Welcome to C.SE.  Very good first question exemplifying the kind of initial research which should be done in an SE site.

Next we will ask: "If God did not create the heavens and the earth, then how do we reconcile this with Genesis 1:1?"

@NigelJ I fail to understand your objection. He quoted 8 sources about the psalm in question in the 2nd paragraph and then goes into detail about even more sources.  He literally did indepth research himself before asking the question... so what standard are you holding him to?

@NigelJ . "The site is not 'Christian'. This is an academic platform which examines, academically, that which is called 'Christianity'" Please refrain from allowing your personal feelings to get in the way of the examination of this question. Certainly a good answer would easily refute the "underlying attack" as you put it.

@Wyrsa I look forward to that answer. And I look forward to up-voting such a contribution in the future. (That would 'refute' such an attack.) As  to my pesonal feelings, well they remain just that. Personal.

It is something I am working on, though I do not know if I will be able to match the original post in the number of sources, I know it is the quality of the sources that matters more. This is a situation where the literalistic interpretation that is so common among many people today is a source of heresy, I do not assume any agenda as you did, I assume that the question is an earnest and honest one albeit with a rather misguided/sinister implication woven through it from what appears to be a logical starting point.

By definition, Jesus made NO mistakes.

@TheChaz2.0 I take your comment in good jest. :)

@Wyrsa Thank you for your comments and answer. I've commented on your answer below. My first comment may help clarify the approach I'm taking and the intent of my question.

This divine oracle introduces a mysterious 'lord', first as a royal figure (VV1-3) then also as a priest (VV4-7). These roles come together in a priest after the order of Melchizedek who is first mentioned in Genesis 14:17-24. David was a king, but could never be a priest. Only Jesus can claim that title.  Luther's commentary on this one psalm runs to 123 pages, but I am not able to access it or answer your question.

E.R. Hardy, Jr., in "The Date of Psalm 110" from Journal of Biblical Literature (1945) argued that the frequent use of God's name in the Psalm argues against a late composition, such as the Maccabean period, when references to the divine name became rare and synonyms used.

@PaulChernoch I also don't see a problem with the Psalm being composed much earlier than the Maccabean period, even during the reign of David himself. Allen (Word Commentary) also agrees the Psalm's themes better fit with a pre-exilic composition and shares an interesting investigation as to what could have been the circustances surrounding the Psalm's composition. My question's main concern was that the evidence seems to point to the Psalm being written about David rather than by David, while Jesus seems to claim the author was David himself. I've attempted to answer my own question below.

@Lesley I agree the Psalm has some enigmatic feaures and is ultimately fulfilled in Jesus, but I don't believe this demands that its original context was entirely futuristic/messianic. The Psalm is "of David" (about David), as other royal Psalms where the king is addressed as "lord" [see Ps. 45:11 for example]. As Allen [Word Commentary] suggests, "The poet appears to celebrate the capture of Jerusalem [where Melchizedek formerly ruled] and David’s accession to the Jebusite throne. His composition is based on two divine oracles, which are cited in vv 1, 4."

"Criticism in the hands of Christian scholars does not banish or destroy the inspiration of the [Scriptures]; it presupposes it; it seeks only to determine the conditions under which it operates... and it thus helps us to frame truer conceptions of the methods which it has pleased God to employ in revealing Himself...." - S. R. Driver[I]
I'd like to set the stage for addressing my own initial questions regarding the doctrine of inerrancy and whether Jesus made an error by first articulating my findings on Christology. At the beginning of this investigation, I thought that Jesus sharing in the divine nature meant that during all of His earthly life, he "[knew] all things" [John 16:30], being in tune with the divine omniscience. But I discovered that this is somewhat of a heterodox position, of which the Scriptures themselves seem to teach otherwise.
Being fully human, Jesus "increased in wisdom" [Luke 2:52]. He didn't know "the day or hour" of His return [Mark 13:32].1 "He expresses surprise on many occasions, and... it was only because the future was not clear that He could pray: 'O my Father, if it be possible, let this cup pass away from me.' [Mat. 26:39] Boldly simple is the language of the inspired commentator on this scene of the agony: 'Christ,' he says, 'in the days of his flesh, having offered up prayers and supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to save him from death, and having been heard for his godly fear, though he was a Son, yet learned obedience by the things which he suffered.' [Heb. 5:8]"2 "In all things He [was] made like His brethren," [Heb. 2:17] 3 having limited knowledge being a likely inclusion.
But how then do we factor in the divine nature of Christ? If we say that He "emptied Himself" [Phil. 2:7] of His divine attributes in the incarnation, how could He still be God if He no longer had the qualities of God? Many would articulate Christ's divine attributes as being "veiled" or "restrained" in the incarnation.4 William Lane Craig suggests that Jesus' divine omniscience was subconscious during his earthly life. "And I feel quite confident that if you had asked Jesus a question about quantum mechanics or auto mechanics, he wouldn't have known the answer to that question, at least in his conscious waking life."5
Yet what do we do about the examples of Jesus exhibiting supernatural knowledge in the gospels? "He saw Nathanael under the fig-tree, and knew the incident in the life of the Samaritan woman, and told Peter how he would find the piece of money in the fish's mouth, and the disciples how they would find the colt tied up in the village, and the man bearing a pitcher of water to take them to the upper chamber. He discerned 'from the beginning' the heart of Judas, and prophesied the denial of Peter, and had in view His own passion, death, and resurrection the third day. But all such supernatural illumination is... analogous to that vouchsafed to prophets and apostles. It is not necessarily Divine consciousness. And it coincides in our Lord with apparent limitations of knowledge."6 Thus the disciples' ascription of Jesus as "know[ing] all things" may be true in respect to His divine nature, yet that divine omniscience is not something which Jesus in His humanity freely accessed. But He, living as a true human in perfect submission to the Father, relied upon that which the Father revealed to Him. [See John 5:19-20, 8:28-29]
Though "there was present to Him the consciousness of His unique Sonship" from a young age"7, it should not surprise us if Jesus would have learned to read and interpret the Scriptures using the rabbinic techniques contemporary to his earthly day. ("Nothing is told us about [Jesus'] education."[8]) Neither should it surprise us if Jesus even followed a rabbi at some point. What is, of course, unique about Jesus is how he doesn't rely upon earlier rabbis and sages to establish the authority of His teaching[9] and how he uniquely applies the Scriptures to Himself [10].
Getting back to the Scripture in question, it seems fair to assume that Jesus himself believes that David wrote Ps. 110, even if David didn't really write the Psalm (rather than assuming that Jesus is "talking down" to his audience because He knows David didn't really write it from the perspective of His divine omniscience). "As far as we can tell, for a first-century Jewish reader 'A psalm of David' would most naturally be taken to mean 'A psalm written by David'"[11], and “it seems fair to suppose that in the NT era a messianic interpretation of Ps 110 was current in Judaism."[12]
Now that I've established a case as to how Jesus could be God yet have limited knowledge and thus believe and use a commonly-held factual error in his argument, the question now remains as to why the Father would allow Him to do so, considering that God cannot lie [Num. 23:19, Titus 1:2, Heb. 6:18] and that Jesus claims that "whatever [he] say[s] is just what the Father has told [him] to say,” [John 12:50 NIV] "the Son can do nothing of Himself, but what He sees the Father do" [John 5:19], and that he "does nothing of [himself]; but as the Father taught [him], [he] speaks these things." [John 8:28]
We should not think that Jesus intended the "nothing" to be so all-encompassing, as if Jesus as a baby was actively watching the Father cry and talk like a baby and that Jesus only got hungry and ate when he watched the Father get hungry and eat. (That would contradict the self-sustaining nature of God.) We should understand His statements more pointedly as referring to supernatural and authoritative "works" the Father does [John 5:17, 20], such as healing [5:8-9, 17], giving life [5:21], pronouncing judgements [5:22, 30], and giving commandments to humanity [12:49-50].
Regarding what Jesus says as being "just what the Father told [him] to say", we should not think that He intends for us to believe that every single word which came out of His mouth was from a divine revelation from the Father, but that His teaching (that which should be received and kept [John 12:47-48]) contained a "message of definite content [from the Father] made over to our Lord to impart".[13]
"But at times He does something besides teaching, He asks men questions such as will lead them to examine themselves closely in the light of their own principles. It is not difficult to select examples: 'If I by Beelzebub cast out devils,' he challenges the Jews, 'by whom do your sons cast them out?' [Mat. 12:27] Here it is not necessary to say that any positive truth is being taught as to Jewish exorcisms, but an appeal is made to our Lord's adversaries to be fair and just in view of their ordinary assumptions. Again, 'Why callest thou me good? There is none good but one, that is God.' [Mark 10:18] Our Lord is not here really disclaiming, as He appears to disclaim, identity in moral goodness with God, but He is leading a young man to cross-question himself as to the meaning of his words, to ask himself what reason he had to address our Lord with a title of deference. It is probable that our Lord was using a similar method in His appeal to the Jews about Psalm 110. On the face of it, the argument suggests that the Messiah could not be David's son,--'if David calleth him Lord, how is he his son?'--but in fact its purpose is not to prove or disprove anything, to affirm or to deny anything, but simply to press upon the Pharisees an argument which their habitual assumptions ought to have suggested to them: to confront them with just that question, which they, with their principles ought to have been asking themselves.... Thus though our Lord lives as man and as teacher in the higher region of the divine word, He still can stimulate and take an interest in the reasonings of men."[14] And "at times, it seems, he was willing to outclass his opponents on their own exegetical grounds."[15]
Matthew, who often modifies the quotes of Jesus found in Mark, to safeguard against misunderstandings for his audience6, may have detected that Jesus didn't intend to make an authoritative statement regarding Davidic authorship of the Psalm ("such an interposition would be a unique phenomenon in His revelation")[17] but perhaps supposes, as I do as well, that Jesus is merely using the commonly-held, theoretical premise as a means to point his audience to recognize "that the Messiah must be considered more than just a junior David, a David redivivus, or even the 'Son of David'—with all the nationalistic overtones that were inherent to that term."[18] This may be why Matthew modifies the form of Jesus' statements according to Mark into a question and a conditional clause, changing "David himself said in the Holy Spirit..."(Mark 12:36) to “How then does David in the Spirit call Him ‘Lord,’ saying...?"(Mat. 22:43) and “David himself calls Him ‘Lord’...."(Mark 12:37) to "If then David calls him 'Lord'..."(Mat. 22:45).
Yet the language of Mark and Luke's versions may still be troubling to some, especially when holding to the doctrine of inerrancy. If it is believed the Bible contains no errors, how do we reconcile this with Jesus' statement (or restatement) of an error? Perhaps it would be helpful to clarify my newfound understanding of such doctrine. I'd like to focus on the New Testament's use of the Tanakh and of Jewish tradition, since these are most relevant to the passage in question.
S. R. Driver put it this way, "There is a human factor in the Bible, which, though quickened and sustained by the informing Spirit, is never wholly absorbed or neutralized by it; and the limits of its operation cannot be ascertained by an arbitrary à priori determination of the methods of inspiration; the only means by which they can be ascertained is by an assiduous and comprehensive study of the facts presented by the [Scriptures themselves]."19 And "H. N. Ridderbos has rightly observed that to claim inspiration by the Spirit for the teaching of Paul 'does not remove the fact that this same Paul in more than one way still betrayed the traces of his rabbinistic education, for instance, in the manner in which he debates, makes use of rabbinic argumentation and traditional materials, and cites the Old Testament.' And Ridderbos goes on to assert quite correctly that such things help us understand the organic character of inspiration in such a way that it 'can also mean connection with certain Jewish or non-Christian elements, without at the same time these elements having been brought under the sanction of revelation and thus belonging to the normative character of Scripture.'”[20]
For example, Paul uses a hyperliteral interpretation of Gen. 13:15 in Gal. 3:16.[21] (Notice Jesus also reads "of David" overly exclusively in regard to authorship in his argument from Ps. 110.)[22] In 1 Cor. 10:1-5, Paul reflects on what he believes to be Israel's literal history and allegorically interprets these events as pointing to Christ. What is striking is that verse five shows that he accepts the theory of "some creative, ancient Jewish interpreters... that the rock at the beginning and the rock at the end were actually one and the same rock,... that one rock had 'obviously' been following the Israelites around in the desert for forty years, sort of like a movable drinking fountain."[23] "In the context of reflecting on all these other understood historical events, Paul just assumes and indirectly affirms on canonical record, some idea about the Israelite wanderings that probably did not happen. For good measure, it even turns out that he’s tied this crazy reference to a direct analogy about his Lord and Savior Jesus."[24] And even Jude, in no uncertain terms, believes that Enoch, "the seventh from Adam," was the author or direct source of his quote from the Book of Enoch, while "no scholars believe the Book of Enoch to have truly been written by the Enoch in the Bible."7
It appears that God permits historical inaccuracies and treatments of Old Testament texts that go beyond historico-critical exegesis in the arguments of the New Testament authority figures and authors, while still bringing about inspired (inerrant) truths through them (the point of their arguments). As in Jesus' use of Psalm 110, we can see the Psalm in more-developed theological terms typologically pointing to a greater fulfillment through the messiah, even if Jesus and His audience had literal authorship in mind to make this point more clearly recognizable. Thus God may not have been so concerned about the logic by which the New Testament authorities reached their conclusions, but that they were able to explicate the sensus plenior (fuller sense) of the Tanakh, “that meaning of [the author's] text which by the normal rules of exegesis would not have been within his clear awareness or intention but which by other criteria we can determine as having been intended by God.”[26]
I think a problem arises when we try to use inerrancy for apologetics, something inerrancy isn't meant to be a tool for.[27] Inerrancy is meant to affirm the reliability of the teaching of the Bible, especially in terms of who God is and man's relationship to God[28], and to distinguish the Bible's unique authority in claims to truth from other religious claims. If then inerrancy is not a proof for the Bible being "of divine origin", then why should we trust it? Well, I think there are other, better reasons to believe it: The marks of design in the origin of the universe and life, fulfilled predictive prophecies, the historicity of the resurrection, supernatural healings and occurrences in the name of Jesus, and other apologetical arguments are worthy methods of pointing us to something that is beyond apologetics, but to the God who inspired the Bible as the most reliable means of teaching us about Himself, and to His Son Jesus Christ, who though subjecting himself to human form with all its limitations, revealed the Father and gave us the words of eternal life.[29]
Notes:
I. An Introduction to the Literature of the Old Testament, pp. XII-XIII. (1903 ed.) This quote was regarding the Old Testament specifically, but he appears to apply the same principles to the New Testament.

I am indebted to Jason for pointing out these two Scriptural examples in his answer to my original post.

Charles Gore, The Incarnation of the Son of God, p. 147-148 (On Jesus expressing surprise, see especially Mark 6:6, 8:21, 11:12-14) (See pp. 145-150 for more on the humanity of Christ.) (Free ebook available through Google Books)

I have to thank Michael for alluding to this Scripture in his answer and subsequent comments.

For a good, though not highly in-depth discussion of different articulations of kenosis theory, see The Remnant Radio, "Kenosis: What did Christ Empty?"

drcraigvideos, "Just how human was Jesus? Wasn't He supposed to be omniscient?"

Gore, The Incarnation, p. 147.

ibid p. 145

ibid

See Mark 11:27-33 and parallels (Mat. 21:23-27, Luke 20:1-8); John 12:49-50

Richard N. Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis in the Apostolic Period, 2nd ed., pp. 44, 55-58, 182 (Logos edition)

Michael L. Brown, Answering Jewish Objections to Jesus, Vol. 3, p. 175 (in Hoopla ebook)

D. M. Hay, Glory at the Right Hand: Psalm 110 in Early Christianity, p. 30 (Quote found in Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis, p. 57, note 56)

Gore, The Incarnation, p. 150

ibid, p. 198-199.

Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis, pp. 53-54 (Here's the quote but with a little more context: "Jesus... used the verbal casuistry of current exegetical practice in a number of his discussions. Evidently, however, he did so principally in an ad hominem fashion, for it is significant that his more atomistic and ingenious treatments of Scripture are in the context of polemical debate with antagonists. At times, it seems, he was willing to outclass his opponents on their own exegetical grounds.")

See Herman Ridderbos, "An Attempt at the Theological Definition of Inerrancy, Infallibility, and Authority", International Reformed Bulletin 32-33, p. 36. Also see Mike Licona's work. This was my introduction to him.

Gore, The Incarnation, p. 197

Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis, p. 57

S. R. Driver, An Introduction to the Literature of the Old Testament, p. XI. (1903 ed.) His quote was regarding the Old Testament specifically, but he appears to apply the same principles to the New Testament. [See pp. XII-XIII] (See also his comments on Jesus' use of Ps. 110: pp. 384-385)

Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis, pp. 197–198 quoting Ridderbos, “The Theological Definition of Inerrancy”, International Reformed Bulletin 32-33, pp. 38-39.

See Michael Brown, Christian Antisemitism, pp. 130-131; "The "Seed" as Christ in Galatians 3:16 and the Wrong Deductions of Replacement Theology," in Stanley E. Porter and Alan E. Kurschner, eds., The Future Restoration of Israel: A Response to Supersessionism

This may have been a generally accepted rabbinic exegetical technique according to Hillel's seven middoth. See Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis, pp. 20-21 for a brief definition of these.

Peter Enns, The Bible Tells Me So: Why Defending Scripture has Made Us Unable to Read It (New York: HarperOne, 2014), pp. 16-17. (Quote found in the following source) I don't necessarily endorse Enns' view on Inerrancy [see Five Views on Biblical Inerrancy], but I haven't looked into it yet to come to a conclusion on the matter.

Ben Stanhope, (Mis)interpreting Genesis: How the Creation Museum Misunderstands the Ancient Near Eastern Context of the Bible, pp. 218-220 (Kindle edition)

Got Questions, "What is the book of Enoch and Should it be in the Bible?" "Most scholars believe the Book of Enoch was written in the second and first centuries BC, not three millennia earlier when Enoch most likely lived. Therefore, the book is pseudepigraphal." [Danny R. Faulkner, "The Book of Enoch and the Flat Earth"] I intentionally chose sources that lean toward evangelical fundamentalism to underscore how indefensible Enoch authoring the Book of Enoch is. Got Questions however further writes, "Evidently, though, the words Jude quotes were genuinely something that Enoch prophesied—or the Bible would not attribute it to him: “Enoch, the seventh from Adam, prophesied about these men” (Jude 1:14). This saying of Enoch was somehow handed down through the generations and eventually recorded in the Book of Enoch." They are in between a rock and a hard place, as they have no evidence whatsoever to defend their conviction.

R. E. Brown, “The Sensus Plenior in the Last Ten Years,” Catholic Biblical Quarterly 25 (1963) 268–269. Quote found in Longenecker, Biblical Exegesis, pp. xxxi – xxxiv (His is quite an informative yet brief discussion of the topic.)

Think of evangelists (like Ray Comfort) who attempt to demonstrate that the Bible was ahead of its time in terms of its scientific knowledge, thus proving that the Bible "must be of divine origin". (Think of the argument that Isaiah 40:22's prophecy describes the earth as being a sphere way before it was discovered that it was, because it says, "He who sits above the circle of the earth..." This argument is frankly misleading, because even flat-earth conceptions of the earth imagined it to be disc-shaped, which is a circle!) Some also attempt to prove the truth claims of the Bible by how "archeology confirms the accuracy of the Bible", thus implying that if the Bible is historically reliable, thus its religious (and claims of supernatural occurences) must be true. While I would agree that the Bible is historically reliable (when read in its proper context), I don't think that is meant to be a proof of its divine authority. It was in large part written by people living during those times, so why wouldn't it be historically accurate?

See Ridderbos, “Definition of Inerrancy”, International Reformed Bulletin 32-33, pp. 30-31

See John 1:18; 7:68



Citing the book of Enoch is an interesting thing to do.

This question while very well researched is an example as to why the Orthodox church requires that conclusions be confirmed by the church as a whole. As the premise that "Christ" made an error is contrary most Christian beliefs.


If the psalm was NOT written by David...

This is a logical assumption/opinion. It is ultimately not actually possible to be certain about who authored each of the Psalms, however I believe you are correct. But you also are correct when you point out that attribution is not equal to authorship.
For a modern example the King James Bible is not written by said king, but it was commissioned by him. Similarly, Psalm 110 is either for David or by David. Judging by the language used "My Lord ... The Lord" we can make a guess that the author is referring to 2 people who aren't themselves.... so Psalm 110 is one of David's Psalms in the sense it is "for him". "of David" is another way to say "about David"  though that is getting into grammar and words which do not affect the meaning or purpose of the Psalm in any way.
I've have been searching for any information about how many psalms might possibly have been written during the reign of King David. And I've not found any concrete data, but I offer a logical assumption. There were more than 75 Psalms written during those years and the Old Testament texts only included those that were the most worthy and inspired by the Holy Spirit.


In what context and with which purpose was Jesus speaking when he said those things in the verses you shared?

Jesus was in the temple answering "trap" questions as well as attempting to share deep meaningful aspects about matters in such a way that people would draw the proper conclusion. This is customary, it is important for people to think about things and understand. Not just to be told the answer.

I will use Mark 12:36a "αὐτὸς Δαυὶδ εἶπεν ἐν τῷ Πνεύματι τῷ Ἁγίῳ" Literally word for word this is "Himself David said by the Spirit+Holy".

Did Jesus believe David was the author?

David was the person to whom everyone around him would understand and respect, and it was also the official opinion that the "owner" of that Psalm was King David at the time Jesus was speaking.
Ultimately it is not possible to know what Jesus thought, but we can understand the situation, cultural context, and purpose (due to hindsight) of what Jesus was doing or saying at any given time. This makes it easy for us to question something and come to some unnatural idea such as "Jesus erred".

If Jesus said that David wrote this Psalm, but it actually wasn't written by David, how do we reconcile that with the doctrine of inerrancy?

Now it is time for more original language Psalm 110 begins with "מִ֫זְמ֥וֹר לְדָוִ֗ד" which translates to "A Psalm ~ Of David" (note right to left reading)
According to the Biblehub website the term "מִ֫זְמ֥וֹר" occurs about 158 times in the Bible. I admit I did not count each one but I looked at the usages outside of the Psalms. I noticed that the most common uses of it are "to David" and "of David"

My answer in the shortest form is this.

Psalm 110 was not written by David, but for David.
Jesus did not make an error, ultimately King David was responsible for Psalm 110. (Directly or Indirectly)
As King David is responsible and officially approved this Psalm, what Jesus said is not a factual error.
The teaching Jesus was attempting to give about his Divine Nature and the lineage of the Messiah via one of David's Psalms would have likely backfired if it wasn't the writing/voice "of David".
I do not see an error, so there is nothing to reconcile.


I fear that my answer and work will be lost when I sign out in a few minutes, forgive my formatting and things I might have missed.


Hi Wyrsa, thank you for taking the time to share your input on how to answer my question. I would certainly not wish to attribute an error to Christ, but I do take skeptical criticisms seriously. I'm willing to follow the truth wherever it leads. And since I'm seeing a seeming contradiction in this passage, either the skeptics are right or I need to change my paradigm on Christology and/or the doctrine of inerrancy. I would much prefer the latter.

While I agree that "ultimately King David was responsible for Psalm 110 (directly or indirectly)... and officially approved [it]"; as you pointed out in your answer, "attribution is not equal to authorship". And as I mentioned in my question, "I also explored the possibility that David could merely be a colloquial designation for the Davidic Psalms, attempting to replace David with the Davidic author in Jesus' quote...."

"... This, however, doesn't seem to work well, since the argument in the gospels revolves around the question of how the messiah could be David's son, whenever David, the assumed author of the Psalm, calls him 'Lord'." The crux of Jesus' argument seems to be based not upon Davidic association with the Psalm but upon Davidic authorship (or at least being the 1st person voice of the quoted portion) of the Psalm.

I have not looked into Church Fathers from the older church, but have you looked into them on this passage in particular? It might be as simple as looking for an old saint's writing on the issue.

Hi Wyrsa, no I haven't looked into them on this passage. I think the church fathers tended to be less critical in their analysis of the Old Testament Scriptures' original context and rather read them very Christocentrically. So I don't think they would see any difficulty with Jesus saying that David wrote the Psalm about the Messiah.

This is an interesting question which is based on the traditional doctrine of the inerrancy of the Bible as well as the inerrancy of Jesus' words. We must confess that these kinds of dogmas are hard to defend in light of objective or scientific Biblical criticism or study. I don't presuppose the Psalm's authorship of the given section as David's in this answer.
The question is closely in line with two popular questions I have seen before:

Did Jesus believe in historical Adam?
"How can Jesus commit a scientific error that the mustard seed is the smallest (Mark 4:31)?"

In the first question, the traditional fundamentalists try to push the idea of historicity of the Genesis stories by pinning it on Jesus. It is a strengthening of their argument to use Jesus as the leverage when the appeal to inerrancy itself fails.
In the second question, however, they would agree that Jesus was speaking within the general knowledge of his time, he did not need to make unnecessary absolute scientific claims of things. These passages should be understood in their cultural and literary context.
It is a matter of convenience to those who hold presuppositional theology and refuse to acknowledge Biblical science or Biblical criticism, which concerns the literature and form of the scripture. The problem lies with dogmas that base all doctrine on a misguided premise, rejecting literature and the subjective nature of interpretations and traditions of ancient times.
For example gotquestions writes this on the historical Adam question:

Christians who deny the story of Adam and Eve essentially deny their own faith. Rejecting the literal interpretation of the Bible’s historical narratives is a slippery slope. If Adam and Eve did not exist, then were Cain and Abel not real? Did Seth exist, and did he father a godly line that led all the way to Abraham and eventually to Jesus Himself? Where in Luke’s genealogy (Luke 3:23–38) do the names stop referring to literal people and start referring to mythical characters? To dismiss Adam and Eve as non-literal is to deny the accuracy of Luke’s gospel, cast aspersions on Moses’ record, and remove the foundation of the rest of the Bible.

Firstly, we need not separate Jesus from the rest of the first-century saints, as you have rightly noted in Brown's argument, which tries to distinguish Jesus' belief from the rest, as if he did not believe what he was saying. Jesus was no different from his brothers. Thus, the apologists are incapable of explaining these things as they are bound to work within the dogmas like inerrancy. I recommend that you study the Talmud to learn how ancient people thought and interpreted the scripture, and also seek a higher level of scholarship.
The belief in Biblical figures like Adam, Moses and David (or the authorship of Pentateuch or Psalms for that matter) has no bearing on the truthfulness of their historicity. You need to understand the ancient people did not separate mythology and history; this distinction of scientific and historical precision in literature is modern. Those Christian scholars who reject the historicity of Adam and Moses don't stop about referring to them and the books of Moses.
The scientific errors found in the Bible are errors only from modern perspective, they were not errors in the ancient culture. For example authorship of books was easily attributed to famous figures to enhance its value, so pseudographs were common, see the apocrypha and gnostic Gospels. None of the Canonical Gospels are definitely known to be written by their traditionally attributed authors, and even some epistles. This doesn't mean we cease to refer to these books with their traditional names; the content makes them valuable, and not the authors, like David or Peter. The falsehood of the NT book's authorship does not mean that today a believer cannot be a spiritual son of Matthew or Peter.
The sonship of Jesus with Biblical figures like Adam and Melchizedek is typological and spiritual. It becomes a problem only when you insist that the genealogies are biological; consider the chain reaction problems caused by the assumption that Jesus' genealogies in Luke and Matthew are to be biological and historical. The main aspect of your question is the problem with Biblical inerrancy, for which I think you should find ways to avoid taking it too rigidly to avoid such hurdles. Serious Christian scholars do not hold to the doctrine of superficial inerrancy or infallibility, as they take into account the human authorship and the historical context. The authors of the Bible were just as human as you are. Do not let anyone undermine your faith by forcing dogmas or rejecting latest scholarship with presuppositions, and by rejecting scholars as 'liberal'.

Michael, thank you for taking the time to share your take on how to resolve my dilemma. To clarify, Dr. Brown didn't draw a distinction between Jesus and "the rest of the first-century saints" but between a "definitive statement" by Jesus and his "pointing to Jewish interpretation of the day". It was my own thinking that drew the distinction between Jesus and other NT authors. I figured that if Jesus shares in the divine omniscience, how could he essentially tell a lie and state that David wrote the Psalm, not merely to accommodate his listeners, but to actually base his argument upon it.

(You wrote, "Jesus was no different from his brothers." I'm curious as to what kind of Christology you would hold to.) I know that divine accommodationism is a sub-articulation of the doctrine of inerrancy that many Christians hold to to account for the technically untrue scientific descriptions in the Bible which are peripheral to what was intended to be conveyed. Would you hold to any form of inerrancy, or would you hold to some other articulation in its place to describe the truthfulness of the Scriptures?

You rightly point out the similarity between my question and the mustard seed dilemma. However, I think my question presents more difficulties, considering the technicality of who authored the Psalm is not peripheral to Jesus' argument but the basis of it. The book I mentioned by Longenecker was certainly a good introduction to Jewish exegetical practices around the 1st century for me. While I better understand them and how Jesus used them, this passage is most difficult for me because his argument appears to be based upon literal authorship, not a typological or allegorical (etc.) argument.

When scholars talk about the NT authors, they also may or maynot use literal actual authorship, but it doesn't mean they believe the traditional names to be actual authors. Jesus did believe David's authorship bec he was living in a time when pple didn't develop such advance distinctions. You'd rather use reasonablefaith mentioning of Jesus divine knowledge being subconscious rather than accomodationism; and it's rather about Jesus, not the inerrancy of bible. Pple basically understand bible is fallible yet go to gr8 lengths to redefine inerrancy to fit the fallibilities. it's unhelpful

All such traditional dilemmas occur when we subconsciously ignore the fact that bible is written by humans by our attribution of divine authorship. There's no need to give arbitrary magical status to the bible or Jesus, as the fundamentalists or Muslim view of Quran. Jesus and Bible are as much human as you are, though Jesus was really God. True humanity of Christology (Heb 2:14 & Paul's), essential for substitutionary atonement. The virgin birth narrative was supposed to be allegorical see https://www.academia.edu/108177200/Luke_and_Jesus_Conception_A_Case_of_Double_Paternity

Brown's argument reducing Christ's words to be pointing out the contemporary interpretation implies that it's isolating Christ with his brothers, as if he was not a true human but pretending to be one to hold back his divine omniscience. This is very unnecessary and absurd as it assumes Jesus to be super human acting to play dumb like Clark Kent. We must defend his true humanity as well as the Holy scripture's (or films) not just canonical books-Bible's true human authorship to avoid the trap of dogmas.

My mention of fallibility also implies rejection of arbitrary Canon list for scripture. Because the authors were ordinary men, but greatly knowledgable. Traditional Xians wouldn't accept my view and would even censor them, so it's hard to even talk about them. But my view which doesn't give a magical status to the bible and tradition, becomes immune to all kind of logical criticism, as we don't have any presupposition here, & we also admit errors bec they're from humans without rejecting the divine source of religion.

It's funny: I actually just searched YouTube for takes on whether Jesus was omniscient and watched a brief clip of Dr. Craig explaining his take. This would certainly be a more settling solution to me, allowing Jesus to use a contemporary human argument (rather than consciously endorsing an error) yet bring out an inspired truth. (I haven't read the article you shared yet. I'm interested in looking into this, though I'd like to formulate a good answer to the question I originally posted and refrain from opening that can of worms until then.)

My view of inerrancy is between a nuanced evangelical and Heiser's [https://drmsh.com/naked-bibles-inspiration-discussion] (Admittedly, I haven't read through his discussion.) I don't see a disparity between affirming inspiration of an agreed-upon canon (2 Tim 3:16) (though I'm open to debates over which books should be included) and acknowledging their human authorship, but there's probably a better thread for discussing that. (I would, however, accept a Jewish/charismatic view, that there can be levels of inspiration in other works, but attributing the highest reliability to the Scriptures.)

I've also had Christian family and friends have a hard time understanding the seriousness with which I take critical analysis, even skeptical criticisms, of Christianity and the Scriptures, often discounting their arguments or just saying to pray the doubts away. But I'm not afraid of facing criticism. There can be no contradiction in truth, and what I believe must accord with reality to be true. And I believe there must be evidence for what is an objective truth. Truth and evidence both are open to criticism, but I believe that God and what is written will be found true.
